# Why can I see the font on this website?

Tags: css, fonts

I was checking out [this website](http://css3gen.com/text-shadow/) which allows you to try out certain features of CSS3. While inspecting its CSS for my own learning purposes, I noticed that the fancy "CSS3Gen" logo uses a font called [Lobster](http://www.dafont.com/lobster.font). I don't have this font installed, and I couldn't find any traces of [web fonts](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_fonts.asp). So why is it that I can see the logo displayed correctly with the Lobster font?

Comment: Please explain any downvotes. I feel this was a legitimate question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They use a link to a font in their head section

`<link  href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster:regular" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >`

Answer (score 2):

Lobster is a google font. If you check the source from the page you can see the linkt to the font:

```
<link  href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster:regular" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
```

You can checkout www.google.com/fonts for more information about google fonts.

Answer (score 1):

Its a css technique called `@font-face`

Google uses this technique to offer a bunch of hosted fonts here... http://www.google.com/fonts

This is a nice article explaining how to use fonts on the web... http://sixrevisions.com/css/font-face-guide/

Comment: There is no @font-face. Read the question please.

Comment: Google fonts uses the @font-face method

Comment: Check the css from the `<link  href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster:regular" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >`

[See here](http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster:regular)